# finding intersection of 2 NSIndexPath arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift2, nsindexpath

I'm trying to find which NSIndexPaths are both visible and selected at the same time. The two arrays are initialised like this:

`let visibleSelectedItems = collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems()`

`let selectedItems = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems()`

I am basically looking for intersection of 2 arrays. Index path is declared as  `NSIndexPath(forItem: Int, inSection: Int)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly as you said - take the intersection. You can do this easily by coercing both arrays to Sets. A Set has an intersection method. You can then coerce back to an array if you need to.